# Relative path not being recognized html/js when using double dots

Tags: javascript, html, path

I have a path to an image: (This is the relative path copied rom VSC)

```
src/sprites/logo.png
```

and if i just write the relative path, it works correctly. with the path looking like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/sprites/trtlogo128.png

But if, instead, I use dots to do the same:

```
../sprites/logo.png
```

i get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

and the path, using a local server, is

> http://127.0.0.1:5500/sprites/logo.png

what is happening to my src folder?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the "If instead i use dots" are you doing this in a url or locally in your file directory?

Comment: locally in my file directory. By dot I meant when I reference the parent directory using '..'